# How to achieve the same function of position:sticky using jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a hard time figuring out why the code below doesn't work as expected.

What I'm trying to achieve is same functionality with `position:sticky` whereas when the scrolled reaches the top of the `#second-header` then fixes its position below the `#header` which is also `fixed`, however, the height of the `#header` is unknown which is I believe can be calculated using the function `outerHeight(true)` on JQuery.

Then after reaching out to the bottom of the `#second-header-container`, remove the fixed position of `#second-header` turning it back to normal position.

Due to browser compatibility issues and other customization, I cannot simply use the `position:sticky` of css.

It looks like my logic is wrong, and I need help.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 var $document = jQuery(document);
 var header = jQuery('#header');
    var second_header = jQuery('#second-header-container').find('#second-header');
 var second_header_container = jQuery('#second-header-container');
  
    var second_header_offset = second_header.offset().top;
 var second_header_container_offset = second_header_container.offset().top;
 
  jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
   var top_margin = header.outerHeight(true);
   var second_header_height = second_header.outerHeight(true);
   var second_header_container_height = second_header_container.outerHeight(true);
    
      if( jQuery(window).scrollTop() > (second_header_offset - second_header_height) && jQuery(window).scrollTop() < second_header_container_height) {  
   second_header.addClass('fixer');
   second_header.css({position:'fixed', top:top_margin, 'z-index':'999999'});
   } else {
   second_header.removeClass('fixer');
   second_header.css({position:'relative', top:'0px', 'z-index':'0'});    
      }
  });
});
```

```css
*{
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.fixer{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

#header, .banner, #second-header, .contents{
  padding: 5px;
}
#header{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 74px;
  z-index: 99999;
  background-color: #000000; 
}
.banner{
  padding-top: 84px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #583E5B;
}
#second-header-container{
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: #775F5E;
}
#second-header{
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-color: #4C3D3C;
}
.contents{
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: #97A36D;
}
.footer{
  background-color: #80A379;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="header">HEADER</header>
<div class="banner">BANNER</div>
<div id="second-header-container">
  <div id="second-header">SECOND-HEADER</div>
  <!--Other contents and elements...-->
</div>
<div class="contents">OTHER...</div>
<footer class="contents footer">FOOTER</footer>
```

Comment: have you tried `position:sticky` in css?

Comment: if `position :sticky` overlaps the `#header` and the `#second header` remove `z-index` for all if mentioned.

Comment: I can't use `position: sticky` due to compatibility issues.

Comment: The code I posted here is just the snippet, I will need to remove the `box-shadow` of the main `header` once the `second-header` becomes visible, the width of `second-header` should 100% fit to left and right of the browser window and etc. So I cannot use `position: sticky`.

Comment: You can use [sticksy.js](https://sticksy.js.org/), with it page content does not crawl under the sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need first check if the scroll height is near the second div header and within the height of the second div. Then add a class that make it stick below the main header. I have created a `sticky` class and added it while scrolling conditions are met.

Please check below code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var headerHeight = $('#header').outerHeight(true);
  var secondHeaderContainer = $('#second-header-container');
  const secondHeaderTopPos = secondHeaderContainer.offset().top;
  const secondHeaderContainerHeight = $(secondHeaderContainer).height();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    const scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    const secondContainerHeightEnd = secondHeaderContainerHeight + secondHeaderTopPos - $('#second-header').height() - headerHeight;

    if (((secondHeaderTopPos - headerHeight) <= scrollTop) && (secondContainerHeightEnd >= scrollTop)) {
      $('#second-header').addClass('sticky').css('top', headerHeight);
    } else {
      $('#second-header').removeClass('sticky');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.fixer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

#header,
.banner,
#second-header,
.contents {
  padding: 5px;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 74px;
  z-index: 99999;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.banner {
  padding-top: 84px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #583E5B;
}

#second-header-container {
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: #775F5E;
}

#second-header {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-color: #4C3D3C;
}

.contents {
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: #97A36D;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #80A379;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="header">HEADER</header>
<div class="banner">BANNER</div>
<div id="second-header-container">
  <div id="second-header">SECOND-HEADER</div>
  <!--Other contents and elements...-->
</div>
<div class="contents">OTHER...</div>
<footer class="contents footer">FOOTER</footer>
```

Comment: Ohh, I see. Thank you.